# Limit returned array values based on offset and condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have documents that contain an array of documents named `versions`. What I would like my query to accomplish is to return all elements from that array that match a specific condition and return a specific amount at a specific offset.

say I have the following documents

```
  {
        title : 'ab',
        versions : [ {name : 'v1',active : false},
                     {name : 'v2', active : true},
                     {name : 'v3', active : true} ]
    }
```

I want to match the title in this case `'ab'` and return all the versions that are active, two at a time, starting from the last element.

I have tried

```
db.versions.find({title : 'ab'}, 
{version : {$elemMatch : {active :true },
             $slice : [offset,limit ] } } );
```

where `offset` is how many entries back into the array should go and `limit` is how many of those entries to return.

I run the query and get the error. ( I accidentally made the active field a string instead of a boolean but this should not matter)

```
"$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue >1 field in obj: 
 { $elemMatch: { active: \"true\" }, $slice: [ -2.0, 2.0 ] }",
        "code" : 17287
```